# find a matching values from 2 arrays, one array having an html element present in it-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 arrays and find the matching values from it, ideally this question has been asked before and seems like it partially works in my case.

lets say I have:

```
var array1 = ["test-123", "id-859","hi-8098", "hello-9090"];
var array2= ["Welcome <span>test-123</span>", "Welcome33 <span>id-859</span>","How are you <span>hi-8098</span>", "Geat <span>hello-9090</span>", "see ya <span>nono-58758</span>"];
```

In my case I have html element `span` and I want to match the values that are inside the `<span>` and return as o/p:

```
var newArray= ["Welcome", "Welcome33 ","How are you ", "Geat "];
```

so basically the values inside array1 matches to all the values inside array2 except the last one`"see ya <span>nono-58758</span>"`. Using filter I can get the matching values, but these values are pretty straight forward,

```
newArray = array1.filter(e => array2.indexOf(e) !== -1); // in my case its undefined, as it does not recognize the html element in it.
```

any ideas on how to get matching values when an html element is present inside an array?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEPS:**

1. Iterate through array1
2. For each string in array1, interate array2
3. Extract the desired text to search by string in array1 (Here I use split)
4. Compare each string from array1 to every extracted text in array2
5. Push the front text if match
6. Trim (optional)

```js
var array1 = ["test-123", "id-859","hi-8098", "hello-9090"]
var array2= ["Welcome <span>test-123</span>", "Welcome33 <span>id-859</span>","How are you <span>hi-8098</span>", "Geat <span>hello-9090</span>", "see ya <span>nono-58758</span>"]

let result = []
array1.forEach(searchStr => {
  array2.forEach(dataStr => {
    let stringInTag = dataStr.split('<span>')[1].split('</span>')[0]
    if (searchStr === stringInTag){
      let text = dataStr.split('<span>')[0]
      result.push(text.trim())
    }
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` don't use with `Array` but `String` . So you need to make string first

```js
var array1 = ["test-123", "id-859","hi-8098", "hello-9090"];
var array2= ["Welcome <span>test-123</span>", "Welcome33 <span>id-859</span>","How are you <span>hi-8098</span>", "Geat <span>hello-9090</span>", "see ya <span>nono-58758</span>"];

var newArr =[];
for(var i of array1) {
  for(var j of array2) {
    var split = j.split("<span>");
    if(split[1].indexOf(i) > -1) {
      newArr.push(split[0]);
    }
  }
}
//newArray = array1.filter(e => array2.indexOf(e) != -1);you don't need this
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

this works too

```js
var array1 = ["test-123", "id-859","hi-8098", "hello-9090"];
var array2= ["Welcome <span>test-123</span>", "Welcome33 <span>id-859</span>","How are you <span>hi-8098</span>", "Geat <span>hello-9090</span>", "see ya <span>nono-58758</span>"];



var k=[];
array2.forEach(a=>{
  array1.forEach(b=>{
if(a.indexOf(b)!=-1){
k.push(a);
}

  })
 
})

let j=k.reduce((o,a)=>{
 let i= a.split("<span>");
 o.push(i[0]);
 return o;
},[])

console.log(j)
```